# Move cursor to the next row when condition satisfies

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, cursor

I have written a cursor to iterate over rows of a table. My requirement is I dont want to check my condition for all the columns. if my condition matches with column 1, then don't check the condition for other columns and move the cursor to the next row. If condition doesn't match with column1 then check for column2 and so on. I have tried using the Break and continue both the keyword but none working as per my requirement. Below is my cursor.

```
Declare @InputResourceId int,@ResourceTypeId int,@CoreAppId int,@SiteId int,@CompetencyID int,@EstaffId int,
@CostCenterId int, @PVLocationId int,@EngineeringCostId int, @CostCategoryId int, @ExpenseTypeId int

Declare InputResourceCursor CURSOR FOR

SELECT InputResourceId, ResourceTypeId,CoreAppId, SiteId, CompetencyId, EStaffId, CostCenterId, PVLocationId
from InputResource where EFITID = 214

OPEN InputResourceCursor

FETCH NEXT FROM InputResourceCursor INTO @InputResourceId,@ResourceTypeId,@CoreAppId,@SiteId,@CompetencyID,@EstaffId,@CostCenterId,@PVLocationId

WHILE (@@FETCH_STATUS = 0)

BEGIN
    
    Declare @Status1 int
    
    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from tblResourceType where ResourceTypeId = @ResourceTypeId)
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
-- Here I want to move my cursor to the next row. If I put my Fetch next here then also its not working properly.
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from tblCoreApp where CoreAppId = @CoreAppId) 
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from tblSiteMaster where SiteId = @SiteId)    
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from tblCompetency where CompetencyId = @CompetencyID)    
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from Estaff where EStaffId = @EstaffId)   
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from CostCenter where CostCenterId = @CostCenterId)   
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    SET @Status1 = (Select Status from PlanViewLocationMaster where PlanviewLocationID = @PVLocationId) 
    IF(@Status1 = 0)
        BEGIN
            UPDATE InputResource SET Status = 2 where InputResourceId = @InputResourceId
        END

    FETCH NEXT FROM InputResourceCursor INTO @InputResourceId,@ResourceTypeId,@CoreAppId,@SiteId,@CompetencyID,@EstaffId,@CostCenterId,@PVLocationId

END

CLOSE InputResourceCursor
DEALLOCATE InputResourceCursor
```

Comment: Do you even need a cursor? You should use set based operations if at all possible.

Comment: I can think of a couple of options: (1) Eliminate the `@Status1` variable assignments and move the status lookups into the `IF` condition. That would allow you to use `ELSE` and structure your code as `IF (Status from ...) = 0 BEGIN ... END ELSE IF ...`. (2) *I really pains me to to say it*, but you can use a `GOTO` - something like `GOTO FetchNext: ... FetchNext: FETCH NEXT FROM ... END`.

Comment: Another option mov all of your status selects inside a single `IF EXISTS(SELECT TOP 1 * FROM (select1 UNION select2 UNION ...) U) BEGIN ... END`, where each `selectN` is of the form `Select Status from ... where ... and Status = 0`.  I believe the `TOP 1` should shortcut the `UNION ALL`, so that once a select is found that satisfies its condition, the remaining selects will be skipped.  This might even be an approach that could be wrapped up into a set operation, eliminating the cursor loop.

Comment: Thanks @TN, Let me try the above approaches. :)

Comment: Code smells. Cursor not required.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe you can move all of your status selects inside a single `EXISTS(select1 UNION ALL select2 UNION ALL ...)` condition, where each `selectN` is of the form `Select <anything> from ... where ... and Status = 0`, similar to your original status lookups. If I understand the likely execution plan, the `EXISTS()` should shortcut the UNION ALL, so that once a select is found that satisfies its condition, the remaining selects will be skipped.

This approach would allow all of your logic to be be wrapped up into a single set operation, eliminating the cursor loop.

```
UPDATE I
SET Status = 2
FROM InputResource I
WHERE I.EFITID = 214
AND EXISTS (
        -- The selected "42 AS Foo" values below are ignored.
        -- We only care about EXISTS().
        Select 42 AS Foo from tblResourceType T where T.ResourceTypeId = I.ResourceTypeId And T.Status = 0
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from tblCoreApp T where T.CoreAppId = I.CoreAppId AND T.Status = 0
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from tblSiteMaster T where T.SiteId = I.SiteId AND T.Status = 0
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from tblCompetency T where T.CompetencyId = I.CompetencyID AND T.Status = 0  
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from Estaff T where T.EStaffId = I.EstaffId AND T.Status = 0
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from CostCenter T where T.CostCenterId = I.CostCenterId AND T.Status = 0 
        UNION ALL
        Select 42 AS Foo from PlanViewLocationMaster T where T.PlanviewLocationID = I.PVLocationId AND T.Status = 0
)
```

Another equivalent alternative is to use a `CROSS APPLY` instead of `EXISTS()`. A cross-apply is like an inner-join to a subselect. If no inner row is matched, the outer row is discarded. An extra subquery layer is needed to implement a `TOP 1` limit to cause shortcutting of the inner selects once a match is found.

```
UPDATE I
SET Status = 2
FROM InputResource I
CROSS APPLY (
    SELECT TOP 1 *
    FROM (
        Select ...
   ) U
) C
WHERE I.EFITID = 214
```

In any case, I would encourage testing to ensure that the result has the intended performance and the shortcut logic is in place to avoid unnecessary subquery executions.  (If you set up a scenario where the first or second subselect matches all, the execution plan should show zero rows accessed for the other selects.)

Lastly, double check that you have appropriate indexes on the tabled referenced  in these subqueries. Most look like PK lookups, so you are likely good.

Comment: Thank you so much @TN for the help. Let me  try the above approach as u suggested. :) Will confirm shortly once I test it thoroughly. Once again thanks

Comment: You don't need top with exists

Comment: `TOP 1` is definitely not necessary in an `EXISTS` or `IN`. You can simplify it to `EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM ... UNION ALL SELECT 1 FROM ...)`

Comment: The query worked like a charm and fixed the issue. Thanks @TN

Comment: The table aliases ought to be used consistently, i.e. `... where T.CoreAppId = I.CoreAppId AND Status = 0` should have a table alias on `Status`. The _select list_ is ignored for `exists` queries, but using `select Status ...` makes it appear, at a glance, like the value is significant (even though it lacks a table alias). My preference is to use `select 42 ...` where `42` is a placeholder to satisfy the syntax requirements, but has no meaning other than being The Answer to the Ultimate Question of Life, the Universe, and Everything.

Comment: Thank you all for the feedback. I removed the `EXISTS(... TOP 1)` variant, added-in the missing aliases, and tweaked/commented the select list.